# In a block transform, how do I insert innerBlocks?

Tags: block-editor

I am creating a block which is created when transformed from a shortcode. In other words, this:

```
[example att1="foo" att2="bar"]
    <p>Inner.</p>
    <p>Content.</p>
[/example]
```

should transform into this a **myplugin/example** block with inner blocks of the two p tags.

So far I've got this, which works fine to get the shortcode attributes.

```
(function(wp){

    wp.blocks.registerBlockType( 'myplugin/example', {
        ...

        attributes: {
            att1 {
                type: 'string',
                default: '',
            },
            att2: {
                type: 'string',
                default: '',
            },
        }, 

        transforms: {
            from: [
                {
                    type: 'shortcode',
                    tag: 'example',
                    attributes: {
                        att1: {
                            type: 'string',
                            shortcode: attributes => {
                                return attributes.named.att1 || '';
                            }
                        },
                        att2: {
                            type: 'string',
                            shortcode: attributes => {
                                return attributes.named.att2 || '';
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
        ...
```

I can get the content by looking at the second parameter in one of those attributes shortcode functions:

```
attributes: {
    att1: {
        shortcode: (attributes, data) => {
             // data.shortcode.content is the shortcode's inner content
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to insert that content as innerBlocks in the output block. The [block registration "transforms" attribute documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-registration/#transforms-optional) is not helpful in this area.

I've tried using the `transform` attribute in the block definition, but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in solution to use a shortcode's inner content as a new block's `innerBlocks`. The best I was able to do is a two step process which first transforms a raw shortcode to the core *shortcode* block, then transform *that* into the new block. In that way I *was* able to use the inner content as innerBlocks.

The reason to do it that way is the "block" transform type has access to a more granular transform function. It ends up looking something like this:

```
     type: 'block',
     blocks: ['core/shortcode'],
     isMatch: function( {text} ) {
        return /^\[slidetoggle /.test(text);
     },
     transform: ({text}) => {

        const initialStateVal = getAttributeValue('slidetoggle', 'initialstate', text);

        const content = getInnerContent('slidetoggle', text);

        const innerBlocks = wp.blocks.rawHandler({
          HTML: content,
        });

        return wp.blocks.createBlock('example/slidetoggle', {
          initiallyClosed: initiallyClosed,
        }, innerBlocks);
     },
  },
```

and the `getAttributeValue` and `getInnerContent` functions look like this:

```
export const getAttributeValue = function(tag, att, content){
    var re = new RegExp(`\\[${tag}[^\\]]* ${att}="([^"]*)"`, 'im');
    var result = content.match(re);
    if( result != null && result.length > 0 )
        return result[1];

    re = new RegExp(`\\[${tag}[^\\]]* ${att}='([^']*)'`, 'im');
    result = content.match(re);
    if( result != null && result.length > 0 )
        return result[1];

    re = new RegExp(`\\[${tag}[^\\]]* ${att}=([^\\s]*)\\s`, 'im');
    result = content.match(re);
    if( result != null && result.length > 0 )
       return result[1];
    return false;
};

export const getInnerContent = function(tag, content, shouldAutoP=true) {
   const re = new RegExp(`\\[${tag}[^\\]]*?]([\\S\\s]*?)\\[\\/${tag}]`, 'i');
   var result = content.match(re);
   if( result == null || result.length < 1 )
      return '';

   if( shouldAutoP == true)
      result[1] = wp.autop(result[1]);

   return result[1];
};
```

For more details on this process, I wrote a [detailed post about this](https://www.bates.edu/webtech/2019/10/07/switching-from-shortcodes-to-blocks-part2/).